# How to lessen the memory spike in between loading scenes

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-development

> Scene A -> Empty -> Scene B

For some reason Scene B always has a big memory spike. The spike is much larger than if I started in Scene B directly. The memory spike seems to around 'unload' statement at the beginning of Scene B. Maybe because of 359 assets unused assets were unloaded? Maybe some of the ones from Scene A? I've tried:

1. Checking for a memory leak but since I can run it in a loop without memory increasing, thats a no.
2. Check to see if scene B has anything expensive at the beginning of scene. Sadly not this either because I removed all the expensive stuff to test.

**Unload Statement before spike**:

```
System memory in use before: 306.8 MB.System memory in use after: 315.3 MB.
    
Unloading 359 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 134403.
```

Comment: Try to learn Adressables and memory profiler.

Comment: Wait you have 134k objects loaded? Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try having it so Scene B is just a prefab and place it in Scene A? Definitely try to limit what's being loaded in, since 134k objects is indeed a lot of things to load in, so that's definitely part of the problem.